# Disable and change color of node in Treeview

Tags: delphi, treeview, nodes, disabled-control

I am looking for the way of **disabling proper nodes**.

Let's say I have created simple **treeview** structure like below:

- Parent 1 *(disable)*
- Parent 2

  - Child 1
  - Child 2 *(disable)*

So far I have found workaround how to do that, but it still doesn't work good at all. I use `OnChanging` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeViewChanging(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
  var AllowChange: Boolean); 
begin
   if (Node.Text = 'Parent 1') or (Node.Text = 'Child 1') then
      AllowChange := False;
end;
```

It works, because I can't click on this node, but the issue is that after 'disabling' node this way, the color of `Parent 1` and `Child 1` nodes is the same as other. Is it any way to change color of this nodes (grey)? Or maybe you know another way to disabling nodes in TTreeView component?

Comment: Set the node's `Enabled` property to `False`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case. It does nothing...

Comment: XP perhaps? TVIS_EX_DISABLED is Vista onward. Or perhaps no runtime themes..

Comment: I use WIN 8 and I don't know why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: In Win7 I can confirm what @David said, Setting `Enabled` to `False` disables the item but also changes the items color to grey. The difference is not very striking if the font color is the standard `clBlack` but still visible.

Comment: Yes, it's weird, but I still need do find workaround for that... Is it any chance to change node color for this disabled items?

Comment: @astack - You can draw the items yourself. You should probably find why "enabled" doesn't work though. Did you try with a brand new project?

Comment: Find *workaround for what* exactly? The faint difference in shading? Draw the item yourself and paint the disabled items in whatever shade or color you want (Windows uses the default enabled/disabled colors with which the user should already be familiar). Enabled works fine; it prevents selection and alters the shading of the item to show it's disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable a node, set its `Enabled` property to `False`. A disabled item is displayed in gray color.

To change the normal color of a nodes text, change `TTreeView.Font.Color`.

To change the color of a disabled nodes text, use the `OnCustomDrawItem`event:

```
procedure TForm2.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if cdsDisabled in state then
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed; //cl3DLight;
end;
```

Default color settings:

[image]

Disabled color = `cl3DLight`:

[image]

Normal text color = `clGreen` and disabled color = `clRed`:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some commentary on Enabled would be nice. So that future readers can know that it does work.

Comment: I did it exactly as you and it works for me. First I disabled proper nodes in my treeview and next I used 'OnCustomDrawItem' event to color this nodes on grey color. Thanks!